# Create an NSArray from JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-plot

I have some data in JSON format which looks like this:

```
{"YrMonth":201109,"StrYrMonth":"Sep-2011","Value":"49275.14"}
{"YrMonth":201110,"StrYrMonth":"Oct-2011","Value":"52087.22"}
etc...
```

Using `NSJSONSerialization` I stored this data in an array called "indicator".
When I want to use this data and display only the items with the key "Value" in a tableView, I can do it fine with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[indicator objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Value"];
    return cell;
}
```

My question is: how can I create an Array that I can use outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the values for each key?
For example:

```
An array for key "StrYrMonth" which contains only: "Sep-2011", "Oct-2011", etc...
An array for key "Value" which contains only: "49275.14", "52087.22", etc...
```

What I would ultimately like to do is use the "Value" array to plot a line in CorePlot and the "StrYrMonth" array to define de x-Axis labels of the graph.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Coding and the `[NSArray valueForKey:]` method ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a))

```
NSArray *strYrMonthArray = [indicator valueForKey:@"StrYrMonth"];
NSArray *valueArray = [indicator valueForKey:@"Value"];
```

Comment: Thanks!! I knew the answer was going to be simple!